# Adding hoverintent to visio generated web page

Tags: jquery, visio, hoverintent

I am using Visio 2010 Professional to generate a workflow web site.  I have edited the Javascript that Visio creates to load the left-hand frame on a mouseover instead of using the Ctrl+Click method that is used by default.  This left-hand frame contains links in it on some of the shapes.  On a very busy page, getting the mouse over to the left-hand frame is nearly impossible without crossing another shape.

I have found hoverIntent on the internet and would like to implement this but I am an absolute newb when it comes to jQuery and Javascript.  How do I go about adding hoverIntent to a Visio shape that looks like the following?

```
<v:shape type="#VISSHAPE"  origHref="" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="1" title="Foo" origTitle="Foo"  style="top:-1000;left:-1000;width:2594;height:2000;position:absolute" path=" m -448,-292 l 90,-292 l 90,-514 l -448,-514 l -448,-292xe" onmouseover="UpdateTooltip(this,42,5)" onclick="OnShapeClick(42,5)" onfocus="UpdateTooltip(this,42,5);" onkeyup="OnShapeKey(42,5)"/>
```

Ideally the hoverIntent would replace the "onmouseover" with something simple.  Let me know if anyone has any idea.  I'll also continue to search Google any help.